# Select an option value from a dynamically created Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I would like to select an option value from a dynamically created drop-down list.

The code below creates the element ,however i'm struggling to make the selection work.

```
var counter = 0;
//options will contain a list of document types from the db
/*
 *  <option value='1'>one</option>
 *  <option value='2'>two</option>
 *  <option value='3'>three</option>
 */
var $options = $("#listDocumentTypes > option").clone();
$.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e[2])), function(i, item) {
      var $selectValue = $('<select class="select optionUpdate" id="ddlDocumentTypeID' + counter + '" name="ddlDocumentTypeID[]">').append($options);

        $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.DocumentLocation.split("/")[item.DocumentLocation.split("/").length - 1]),
        $('<td>').text(ite.FileSize),
        $('<td>').text(item.DocumentDescription),
        $('<td>').html($selectValue.prop('outerHTML')),
        $('<td>').html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='delete file' value='" + item.DocumentID + "'  class='btn btn-default txt-color-red deleteFile'><i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'></i></a>"),
      );

      //selection is failing here
      $("#ddlDocumentTypeID" + counter + "").val(item.DocumentTypeID).attr("selected", "selected");
      counter++;
    }
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: are you trying to select a element that wasn't even added to DOM yet? It won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED It.

basically using array.find on the $option and setting the attribute of selected

```
 var option =Array.from($options).find(x => x.getAttribute("value") == item.DocumentTypeID);
      option.setAttribute("selected","selected");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Pfunzo/e57rdpng

Answer (score 0):

Set the value on the object `$selectValue` and append the whole object not just the outerHTML

The reason it's not working as shown is you haven't added that row into the dom so searching for it there will return nothing

```
$.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e[2])), function (i, item) {

        var $selectValue = $('<select class="select optionUpdate" id="ddlDocumentTypeID'+counter+'" name="ddlDocumentTypeID[]">')
         .append($options); 
         // set value here
         .val(item.DocumentTypeID)


        $tr = $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.DocumentLocation.split("/")[item.DocumentLocation.split("/").length-1]),
            $('<td>').text(ite.FileSize),
            $('<td>').text(item.DocumentDescription),
            // append whole object
            $('<td>').append($selectValue.),
            $('<td>').html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' title='delete file' value='"+item.DocumentID+"'  class='btn btn-default txt-color-red deleteFile'><i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'></i></a>"),


        );


        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: That demo doesn't do what I suggested

Comment: The demo was to show what i've done. i've updated it have your suggestion, like i've said before, I had tried that, it yields the same results